# My Android app is initialy making me select a photo. Instead, I want my app to initially take me to the main page

Tags: java, android, android-imageview

When I start my app, it initially makes me select a photo. Instead, I want it to take me to the main screen, where I can select a photo when I want to.  It is already programmed to select a photo when I click on the imageview.  And just to clarify, the problem is that it forces me to select a photo when I start the app, not anytime else

```
    public void getPhoto() {
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
        startActivityForResult(intent,1);
    }

        @Override
        public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
            super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);

            if (requestCode ==1){
                if (grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED);{
                getPhoto();
                }
            }
        }

    @Override
            protected void onCreate (Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
                setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

if (checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
                requestPermissions(new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, 1);
            } else {
                getPhoto();
            }

        }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);


        if (requestCode ==1 && resultCode == RESULT_OK && data != null) {
            Uri selectedImage = data.getData();

            try {
                Bitmap bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(this.getContentResolver(), selectedImage);


                ImageView imageView2 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView2);
                imageView2.setImageBitmap(bitmap);


            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    public void click(View view) {
        if (checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
            requestPermissions(new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, 1);
        } else {
            getPhoto();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: remove the `getPhoto()` call from `onCreate()` ?

Answer (score 1):

Pretty much as Droidman says.

```
if (checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
            requestPermissions(new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, 1);
        } else {
            getPhoto();
        }
```

You are checking for permissions. If you have the correct permission, you call getPhoto() straight away in your onCreate. Remove this call and it will be fine.